# Google Analytics: How to get events over last 90 minutes

Tags: google-analytics, real-time, google-analytics-api

I'm going to be to using the Google Analytics API/Real Time API.

The problem with the Google Analytics API is that it's usually delayed by two-three hours. Thus, I can't get metrics for the last XX minutes.

The problem with the Real Time API is that it only displays "active" users, and so if relying on it solely I'd missing some data.

What I want to build is a dashboard of sorts that shows the most occurring events over a timespan of 30, 60, 90, 120 minutes. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data from the realtime API into a database every few minutes and write a query that sums up the results for the last 30,60,90 etc minutes (that might also avoid running into API quota limits). If you're a 360 Suite customer you could do a streaming export to Bigquery (which basically amounts to the same thing).

Apart from that workaround there really isn't anything in GA to fill the gap between realtime and standard reports.

Comment: Piersorff thanks. I was hoping to avoid that. Do you know if hits/events have their own ID? meaning - would I be able to discern between user 1,2,3 if they appear in different real-time reports? otherwise I'd be summing the same user twice etc..

Comment: No. Or actually yes, they have an Id, but that's not exposed anywhere. Realtime isn't really a well defined concept in Google Analytics, so aiming for precision is probably hopeless in any case.

Comment: Eike - so there is really no mostly-precise way to count the number of distinct hits on an event in the last (say) 120 minutes?

Comment: Depends on how hacky you want your workarounds to be. You could set a custom dimension with a unique identifier, use a view filter to copy that to one of the realtime data fields you feel you don't need (rt:pageTitle or something) and then query that field in the realtime API to get a unique value to deduplicate data. You probably would want to do this in a separate view so it does not affect the permanent reports. Untested, but sounds like it might just work.